# How to document.getElementById with more than one ID?

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

how can I add more than one ID in the following code?

```
function myFunction() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

I have tried tried it with querySelectorAll but then no popup shows?

```
 function myFunction() {
    var popup = document.querySelectorAll("#myPopup, #myPopup2");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList` which must be traversed through to access each element:

```js
document
  .querySelectorAll('#myPopup, #myPopup2')
  .forEach(function(element){
    element.classList.toggle("show");
  })
```